# Proof: For any arbitrary $m \times n$ matrix $A$, there exists an unique $n \times m$ matrix $P$ that satisfies the equation

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices

I ran into the following problem:

> Prove that any arbitrary $m \times n$ matrix $A$, there exists an unique $n \times m$ matrix $P$ that satisfies the following equations:
> $$\begin{cases} APA = A \\ PAP = P \\ (AP)^T = AP \\ (PA)^T = PA \end{cases}$$

What I've done so far:

- <del>From equations (1) and (3), we get $(AP)^TA = A \Rightarrow (AP)^T = (AP)^{-1}$ so $AP$ is an orthogonal matrix.</del>
- <del>Similarly, from equations (2) and (4), $PA$ is also an orthogonal matrix.</del>
- If $A$ has independent columns, $APA = P^TA^TA = A \Rightarrow P = A(A^TA)^{-1}$ also $APA = AA^TP = A \Rightarrow P = (A^TA)^{-1}A$. But I have no idea what to do when $A^TA$ isn't invertible.
- Using singular value decomposition, $A = U\Sigma V^T = APA$ implies $P = V\Sigma U^T$

I've read [this post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3161466/proving-matrices-equation-when-all-the-matrices-in-it-may-not-be-invertible), which I had a difficult time trying to understand it.
Hoping for some direction to think; I really wonder how to prove that there is a unique $P$ for any $A$. Any tips help, and thanks in advance.

Edit: now I've got some sleep, and found out that I'm wrong about the first two points.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057644/why-svd-is-not-unique-but-the-moore-penrose-pseudo-inverse-is-unique) might be helpful.

Comment: @VarunVejalla Thanks, let me take a look.

Comment: The statement as it stands is false. Consider $A=\pmatrix{1\\ i}$ for instance. If $AP$ is symmetric, $P$ must be a scalar multiple of $A^T$. But then $PA=0$ (because $A^TA=0$) and hence $APA=0\ne A$. To correct the statement that you want to prove, you need to either assume that $A$ is a real matrix or change all occurrences of matrix transpose to conjugate transposes.

Comment: @user1551 I think from the question it is fairly obvious this is about _real_ matrices (and really about Euclidean vector spaces). In the case of complex vector matrices the transposition should be combined with complex conjugation, as you probably know very well.

Comment: This is really a duplicate to the question OP linked to; asking the same question again with "I don't understand the answer given there" is not really helpful. I've given an answer to the linked question and then closed this one; as usual anyone wanting to answer this question is invited to add an answer to the one it is a duplicate of.